# How do I attach an event to a third party library

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dojo

I am using a library called dojo and I am using a `ValidationTextBox` which I am trying to hook up an event to.  There is a fairly popular autotab plugin which I am trying to use but I cannot attach an event to my textboxes.

The plugin is at https://github.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab

Here is my code:

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" maxlength="3" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" class="tryingAutoTab" />
<input id="Text2" name="Text2" type="text" maxlength="4" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" class="tryingAutoTab"/>
```

and on document ready I call:

```
$("#Text1").autotab({ format: 'tryingAutoTab', target: '#Text2' });
```

this works perfectly if I don't use a dojo textbox.  Anyone have any experience with dojo that might have an idea?

Comment: Is the ValidationTextBox properly `require`'d?

Comment: yeah, the design was chosen and it would be a bit of work to mimic all of the behaviours the dojo textbox has to a normal textbox.

Comment: I'd pick Dojo or jQuery, not both. If you choose Dojo, try implemeting the auto-tab functionality. If you choose jQuery, look for a validation  plugin.

Comment: Actually I got it working, I answered the question myself.  You can get the native textbox from the the dojo textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the native textbox and work with that.

```
var _textBoxNative = $(dojoTextBoxInstance.textbox);
```

so here it is:

```
$(dijit.byId("Text1").textbox).autotab({ target: dijit.byId("Text2").textbox });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to combine those two that easy. Dojo 'wraps' these input elements and add their own events like blur, focus, click. Sometimes they even get rebuild completely, without knowing about any jquery attached events or anything.